# hyperledger fabric multi host error with connection orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm

I am trying to connect multi host with hyperledger fabric 1.2.

I used docker swarm with virtualbox.

I executed this code with PC1.

```
docker swarm init
docker swarm join-token manager
docker network create --attachable --driver overlay byfn
```

and executed code like this to make it join PC1.

```
docker swarm join — token SWMTKN-1–3as8cvf3yxk8e7zj98954jhjza3w75mngmxh543llgpo0c8k7z-61zyibtaqjjimkqj8p6t9lwgu 172.16.0.153:2377
```

and executed each PC1 command in a separate terminal on PC1.

and executed each PC2 command in a separate terminal on PC2.

but, when I execute cli command, error occurred.

```
2018-08-07 01:53:32.659 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 040 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {0.0.0.0:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7050: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
2018-08-07 01:53:32.659 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 041 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420460ad0, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2018-08-07 01:53:34.326 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 042 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420460ad0, CONNECTING
2018-08-07 01:53:34.328 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 043 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {0.0.0.0:7050 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7050: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
2018-08-07 01:53:34.328 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 044 pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420460ad0, TRANSIENT_FAILURE
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
```

### orderer error logs

```
2018-08-07 06:29:04.357 UTC [grpc] Println -> DEBU 0c6 grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"\\x16\\x03\\x01\\x00\\xb2\\x01\\x00\\x00\\xae\\x03\\x03\\x04w\\xffLbc0\\x94\\xec\\x8cV\\xdfa\""
2018-08-07 06:29:05.340 UTC [grpc] Println -> DEBU 0c7 grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"\\x16\\x03\\x01\\x00\\xb2\\x01\\x00\\x00\\xae\\x03\\x03\\xb6\\x8cU-\\xfa\\xd8&\\x8fp\\x16(:\\xa4\""
2018-08-07 06:29:07.053 UTC [grpc] Println -> DEBU 0c8 grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"\\x16\\x03\\x01\\x00\\xb2\\x01\\x00\\x00\\xae\\x03\\x03\\xfe\\xcf\\xd1\\xea,7we\\xa3\\x10Γ\\x06\""
```

I refer to this site.

https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

Network Topology

PC1

- CA0
- CA1
- ORDERER
- PEER0(ORG1)

PC2

- PEER0(ORG2)
- CLI

### PC1

### CA0

```
docker run --rm -it --network="byfn" --name ca_peerOrg1 \
-p 7054:7054 \
-e CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=byfn \
-e FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server \
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1 \
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true \
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem \
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/e723fd0eac7f338381b2bb7f74b417ae42ed28b3c47faaa119837f2405c337da_sk \
-v $PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config \
hyperledger/fabric-ca \
sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/e723fd0eac7f338381b2bb7f74b417ae42ed28b3c47faaa119837f2405c337da_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
```

### CA1

```
docker run --rm -it --network="byfn" --name ca_peerOrg2 
-p 8054:7054 
-e CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=byfn 
-e FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server 
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2 
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true 
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem 
-e FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/3d8b514fa72a496e6715413d4c2dec90c335c827c7049a8de0aa712435ce1f7f_sk 
-v $PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config 
hyperledger/fabric-ca 
sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/3d8b514fa72a496e6715413d4c2dec90c335c827c7049a8de0aa712435ce1f7f_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
```

### orderer

```
docker run --rm -it --network="byfn" --name orderer.example.com \
-p 7050:7050 \
-e CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=byfn \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0 \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050 \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=false \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt \
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt] \
-v $PWD/channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block \
-v $PWD/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp \
-v $PWD/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls \
-v orderer.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer \
-w /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric \
hyperledger/fabric-orderer \
orderer
```

### peer0

```
docker run --rm -it --network="byfn" --name peer0.org1.example.com \
--link orderer.example.com:orderer.example.com \
-p 7051:7051 \
-p 7053:7053 \
-e CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=byfn \
-e CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com \
-e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
-e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
-e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
-e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock \
-e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true \
-e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true \
-e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false \
-e CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt \
-v /var/run/:/host/var/run/ \
-v $PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp \
-v $PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls \
-v peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production \
-w /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer \
hyperledger/fabric-peer \
peer node start
```

### PC2

### peer0

```
docker run --rm -it --network="byfn" --name peer0.org2.example.com \
--link orderer.example.com:orderer.example.com \
-p 9051:7051 \
-p 9053:7053 \
-e CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=byfn \
-e CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com \
-e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 \
-e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051 \
-e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP \
-e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock \
-e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true \
-e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true \
-e CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false \
-e CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt \
-v /var/run/:/host/var/run/ \
-v $PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp \
-v $PWD/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls \
-v peer0.org2.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production \
-w /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer \
hyperledger/fabric-peer \
peer node start
```

### cli

```
docker run --rm -it --network="byfn" --name cli \
--link orderer.example.com:orderer.example.com \
--link peer0.org1.example.com:peer0.org1.example.com \
--link peer0.org2.example.com:peer0.org2.example.com \
-p 12051:7051 \
-p 12053:7053 \
-e CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=byfn \
-e GOPATH=/opt/gopath \
-e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock \
-e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG \
-e CORE_PEER_ID=cli \
-e CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051 \
-e CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key \
-e CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt \
-e CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp \
-v /var/run/:/host/var/run/ \
-v $PWD/crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ \
-v $PWD/scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/ \
-v $PWD/channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts \
-v $HOME/fabric-samples/chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode \
-w /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer \
hyperledger/fabric-tools \
/bin/bash \
-c './scripts/script.sh'
```

### script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
echo " ____    _____      _      ____    _____ "
echo "/ ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|"
echo "\___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |  "
echo " ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ <    | |  "
echo "|____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|  "
echo
echo "Build your first network (BYFN) end-to-end test"
echo
CHANNEL_NAME="$1"
DELAY="$2"
LANGUAGE="$3"
TIMEOUT="$4"
VERBOSE="$5"
: ${CHANNEL_NAME:="mychannel"}
: ${DELAY:="3"}
: ${LANGUAGE:="golang"}
: ${TIMEOUT:="10"}
: ${VERBOSE:="false"}
LANGUAGE=`echo "$LANGUAGE" | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
COUNTER=1
MAX_RETRY=5

CC_SRC_PATH="github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/"
if [ "$LANGUAGE" = "node" ]; then
CC_SRC_PATH="/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/node/"
fi

echo "Channel name : "$CHANNEL_NAME

# import utils
. scripts/utils.sh

createChannel() {
    setGlobals 0 1

    if [ -z "$CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED" -o "$CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED" = "false" ]; then
            set -x
    peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx >&log.txt
    res=$?
            set +x
else
            set -x
    peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA >&log.txt
    res=$?
            set +x
fi
cat log.txt
verifyResult $res "Channel creation failed"
echo "===================== Channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' created ===================== "
echo
}

joinChannel () {
for org in 1 2; do
    for peer in 0 1; do
    joinChannelWithRetry $peer $org
    echo "===================== peer${peer}.org${org} joined channel '$CHANNEL_NAME' ===================== "
    sleep $DELAY
    echo
    done
done
}

## Create channel
echo "Creating channel..."
createChannel

## Join all the peers to the channel
echo "Having all peers join the channel..."
joinChannel

## Set the anchor peers for each org in the channel
echo "Updating anchor peers for org1..."
updateAnchorPeers 0 1
echo "Updating anchor peers for org2..."
updateAnchorPeers 0 2

## Install chaincode on peer0.org1 and peer0.org2
echo "Installing chaincode on peer0.org1..."
installChaincode 0 1
echo "Install chaincode on peer0.org2..."
installChaincode 0 2

# Instantiate chaincode on peer0.org2
#echo "Instantiating chaincode on peer0.org2..."
#instantiateChaincode 0 2

# Query chaincode on peer0.org1
#echo "Querying chaincode on peer0.org1..."
#chaincodeQuery 0 1 100

# Invoke chaincode on peer0.org1 and peer0.org2
#echo "Sending invoke transaction on peer0.org1 peer0.org2..."
#chaincodeInvoke 0 1 0 2

## Install chaincode on peer1.org2
#echo "Installing chaincode on peer1.org2..."
#installChaincode 1 2

# Query on chaincode on peer1.org2, check if the result is 90
#echo "Querying chaincode on peer1.org2..."
#chaincodeQuery 1 2 90

echo
echo "========= All GOOD, BYFN execution completed =========== "
echo

echo
echo " _____   _   _   ____   "
echo "| ____| | \ | | |  _ \  "
echo "|  _|   |  \| | | | | | "
echo "| |___  | |\  | | |_| | "
echo "|_____| |_| \_| |____/  "
echo

exit 0
```

Comment: Did you try by disabling the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems could be that you have an old version of the **cryptogen tool**, if you are pointing to an old version of it, your crypto files must be all corruped, you should always point to your version downloaded with the examples.

Another solution can be disable the firewall in both PCs, be sure that they can see each other, and open the correspondant ports, also you should add a `extra-hosts` section to your docker compose files (check the link below, I talk about that in the blog)

If you had run lot of tests, clean all images and containers, that always help.

If nothing of that works, I wrote a tutorial based on the basic-network example and how to run it in multiple hosts, maybe you can take some information from there.

[Setup Hyperledger Fabric in multiple physical machines](https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4)

Please, feel free to ask, if you have doubts!

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the same issue just deleting all docker images of fabric and the volumes too. And re installed with the fabric version 1.2.0-rc1`curl -sSL http:// url /2ysbOFE | bash -s 1.2.0-rc1` url: bit dot ly I can't post that url

Edit: you can check if your docker containers have some capabilities troubles? with docker logs _container_name_
In container name you should put the container name of the dead container, you can check out with `docker ps -a`, the 'exit (n time) ago'.
If you have capabilities troubles please put capabilities like that [capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tikz.png) there are in configtx.yaml